# How to pick one val loss value for Earlystopping , when multiple losses are returned

Tags: keras, early-stopping

I am training a Variational Autoencoder with custom losses, which has three components

1. total_loss
2. reconstruction_loss
3. kl_loss

The code is too big, I hope the snippet articulates my problem **(The running code is** **[here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_y5xmhdS2YW2j1YHzm4d6Z-ZWOlLiUTD?usp=sharing) in colab**). With these two functions I am able to train my model and at the end of every epoch I am able to get the values for all three losses.

```
def train_step(self, data):
    if isinstance(data, tuple):
        data = data[0]
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(data - reconstruction),
                                             axis = [1,2,3])
        reconstruction_loss *= self.r_loss_factor
        kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis = 1)
        kl_loss *= -0.5
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
    grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
    return {
        "loss": total_loss,
        "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
        "kl_loss": kl_loss,
    }

def test_step(self, input_data):
    validation_data = input_data[0] # <-- Seperate X and y
    z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(validation_data)
    val_reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
    val_reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(validation_data - val_reconstruction),
                                 axis = [1,2,3])
    val_reconstruction_loss *= self.r_loss_factor

    val_kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
    val_kl_loss = tf.reduce_sum(val_kl_loss, axis = 1)
    val_kl_loss *= -0.5
    val_total_loss = val_reconstruction_loss + val_kl_loss
    return {
        "loss": val_total_loss,
        "reconstruction_loss": val_reconstruction_loss,
        "kl_loss": val_kl_loss,
    }
```

However, if I insert a earlystopper in the call backs like this:

```
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.001, patience=10)
```

I get an error at epoch end

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

My hunch is , the earlystopper is getting 3 values to judge from. How can I select only the total val loss for judging early stopping condition

Comment: The issue is that your losses are arrays, you need to average over the batch axis to get scalars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling , I finally found the answer I was looking for [here](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/). It turns out , I had to make the following modifications. 
 Add these attributes to the VAEModel class ( [**colab notebook here**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_y5xmhdS2YW2j1YHzm4d6Z-ZWOlLiUTD?usp=drive_link) )

```
self.total_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
self.kl_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

self.val_total_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
self.val_reconstruction_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
self.val_kl_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")
```

Add two properties ( 1 each for train and val )

```
@property
def metrics(self):
    return [
        self.total_loss_tracker,
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
        self.kl_loss_tracker,
    ]

@property
def val_metrics(self):
    return [
        self.val_total_loss_tracker,
        self.val_reconstruction_loss_tracker,
        self.val_kl_loss_tracker,
    ]
```

And finally in the train and test steps I was able to access the losses by adding these lines

```
# Add to the train step    
self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

return {
  "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
  "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
  "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        } 


# Add to the test step
self.val_total_loss_tracker.update_state(val_total_loss)
self.val_reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(val_reconstruction_loss)
self.val_kl_loss_tracker.update_state(val_kl_loss)

    
return {
    "loss": self.val_total_loss_tracker.result(),
    "reconstruction_loss": self.val_reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
    "kl_loss": self.val_kl_loss_tracker.result(),
    }
```

The full working version is available in colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_y5xmhdS2YW2j1YHzm4d6Z-ZWOlLiUTD?usp=drive_link). Now the early stopping is able to access the losses as a single values. In all honesty , it'd take me a while to understand , why its working. Nevertheless , my code is at least functional.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The EarlyStopping callback is expecting a single value for monitoring, but in your test_step function, you are returning a dictionary with three values.

## Solution

I suggest to call the stopper on the metric you want to monitor. Your expanded code (Notice I assume thsat your data is already batched):

```py
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_total_loss', min_delta=0.001, patience=10)
num_epochs=1

# Your training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Training step
    for batch in train_data:
        train_results = model.train_step(batch)
    
    # Validation step
    val_results = []
    for batch in val_data:
        val_results.append(model.test_step(batch))
    
    # Average validation losses
    avg_val_total_loss = tf.reduce_mean([result["val_total_loss"] for result in val_results])
    avg_val_reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean([result["val_reconstruction_loss"] for result in val_results])
    avg_val_kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean([result["val_kl_loss"] for result in val_results])
    
    # Use the total validation loss for early stopping
    should_stop = early_stopper.on_epoch_end(epoch, avg_val_total_loss)
    
    # Check if early stopping criteria are met
    if should_stop:
        break
```